# The flow failed to access the value for locationlwc.location.Geolocation__Latitude__s because it hasn't been set or assigned

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have an lwc which gets the geolocation latitude and longitude. I am passing it to a flow. I added console log and I can see the latitude and longitude set in the logs . I can also see in the flow debug logs the values for latitude and longitude. Still I am getting this error and I am not able to store the latitude and longitude values.

```
setLocationRecord() {
    console.log(this.parsedResponse);
    this.locationRecord.Street__c = this.checkAddressComponents('address');
    this.locationRecord.City__c = this.checkAddressComponents('city');
    this.locationRecord.State_Province__c = this.checkAddressComponents('region');
    this.locationRecord.Country__c = this.checkAddressComponents('country');
    this.locationRecord.Zip_Postal_Code__c = this.checkAddressComponents('postal');
    this.locationRecord.County__c = this.checkAddressComponents('subregion');
    this.locationRecord.Geolocation__latitude__s= this.checkAddressComponents('y');
    this.locationRecord.Geolocation__longitude__s = this.checkAddressComponents('x');
    this.originalRecord = this.locationRecord;

    console.log('Inside setLocationRecord');
    console.log(this.locationRecord.Geolocation__latitude__s);
    console.log(this.locationRecord.Geolocation__longitude__s);

    this.handleSetLocation();
}

handleSetLocation() {
    this.location = this.locationRecord;
    console.log('Chosen record');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.location));
    // notify the flow of the new todo list
    const attributeChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('location', this.location);
    this.dispatchEvent(attributeChangeEvent);
}

checkAddressComponents(type) {
    var value;
    var location = this.parsedResponse.candidates[0].attributes;
    Object.keys(location).forEach(function(attr) {
        if(type === attr) {
            value = location[attr];
        }
    });        
    return value;
}
```

I am also saving the city,state,country,zip. All are getting passed from lwc to the flow and getting saved also.

What am I doing wrong here? Please help.Thanks

```
<

?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
        <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    
        <masterLabel>Location Search</masterLabel>
        <description>Geocode searching</description>
        <targets>
            <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
        </targets>
        <targetConfigs>
            <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
               <property name="location" label="Location" type="@salesforce/schema/Location__c" description="Attributes of the location"/>
                <!--<property name="latitude" type="String"/>!-->
            </targetConfig>
        </targetConfigs>
    
    </LightningComponentBundle>
```

In the flow I can see the output latitude and longitude , but when i try to display the values it is giving me error.

> Lightning Component: geocodeLocation Screen component: c:location
> Inputs: Outputs: location = [Location__c
> (Geolocation__longitude__s:-70.65522699999997,
> Geolocation__latitude__s:42.67836100000005, Street__c:1123 Washington
> St, Zip_Postal_Code__c:01930, County__c:Essex County, Country__c:USA,
> City__c:Gloucester, State_Province__c:Massachusetts)]

The error is

> Error element test_screen (FlowScreen). The flow failed to access the
> value for geocodeLocation.location.Geolocation__Latitude__s because
> it hasn't been set or assigned.

Comment: can you post the whole code for your component?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Got it resolved. It was because of case sensitivity./

Comment: Great!! I am glad you solved it